# Finding the names of the running activities

Tags: android

**Edited to change 'running to 'running or paused and in background'**

Is there a method which which I can log the names of the classes of the activities running or paused and in the background (i.e. not finished) in my application?

I find the shell command **adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.mypackage.myapp** to be most useful in managing the activity stack but it only gives me the number of activities running, not their names.

For example on startup it gives me this snippet:

```
** MEMINFO in pid 215 [com.mypackage.myapp] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:     4336     3203      N/A     7539
       allocated:     4326     2527      N/A     6853
            free:        9      676      N/A      685
           (Pss):     1034     1974     1994     5002
  (shared dirty):     2160     4732     1564     8456
    (priv dirty):      864      684      912     2460

 Objects
           Views:       22        ViewRoots:        2
     AppContexts:        3       Activities:        2
          Assets:        2    AssetManagers:        2
   Local Binders:        7    Proxy Binders:       11
Death Recipients:        0
 OpenSSL Sockets:        0
```

Now I reckon I should only have one activity occupying memory, yet it tells me there are two. I'd quite like to know what the other one is.

Comment: nice question I am also keen to know how to get info of Running Activities in app

Answer (score 0):

As soon as an activity has lost focus and another activity runs the first one is paused or stopped. The conclusion is that there is always just one activity really running and that is the visible activity on the foreground.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, namely "how can I find the names of running activities?"

Comment: My answer says that there is only one activity running, you can't get a list of the current running activities since only one is running. If you want to log it, I'd just add a log in the activity itself that it is running. All others aren't at that moment.

Comment: When @NickT says "running activities", he wants to include paused activities.